# MKMapview requests location tracking in background by default in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, ios8, cllocation

In iOS 8 the MKMapView requests by default the permission to track the user's location even when the app is in the background. Is there any way to change this, so as to request only the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription permission?

I am not using a custom CLLocationManager, since I do not need it for anything else apart from displaying the user location on the map. Is it possible to avoid using a custom CLLocationManager?

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can use location without the user giving permission. Imagine the problems if everyone could just track a device location without the user's knowledge?

Comment: I think you did not understand the question: "I am not using a custom CLLocationManager, since I do not need it for anything else apart from displaying the user location on the map. Is it possible to avoid using a custom CLLocationManager?"

Comment: "since I do not need it for anything else apart from displaying the user location on the map" Well if you don't use the tools needed for obtaining the location I can't see how.